# New as new can be to this. Needed password reset. Now cant login at all

Tags: login, password

Well. I forgot the password to my laptop. So I asked a friend from work if there was anything that could be done about it. So, of course. I let him "fix" it for me. Now when I try to login. It accepts the password. Then goes to a black screen. It shows some text in the upper left hand corner for a very very brief moment. Then goes directly back to the login screen. The text shown appears to be (I took a blury picture of it)

```
-Starting postgre3QL

-Starting openbravo-postgresq1
Removed stale pid file

-Starting openbravo-tomcat
```

Keep in mind its a very blurry picture so it may not be 100% acurate. But thats the best I can make it out.

I can login to the guest session just fine. I'm running any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of resetting the password if you have physical access, and I'll look that up afterwards. An easier way, assuming that you don't mind changing your user name is to boot a live Ubuntu from a USB drive and them reinstall alongside your existing version using a different username. You should have full access to the data tat is already there.

Before that though, if you think you know what your password is now, after you boot, press ctl-alt-F1 to bring up a terminal session. Type your username, then password and see if you can get in using the console. After that we can see if the problem with graphics can be resolved.